# how to fix Ionic Gradle error when ionic cordova build android?

Tags: ionic3

ANDROID_HOME=D:\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_144
Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).

And my ionic info is:

cli packages: (C:\Users\Qsek PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.11.0
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : D:\sdk

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Download the latest Gradle distribution here.

Then create a new directory **C:\Gradle** with File Explorer.

Unzip the content inside this folder.

After that, under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for **C:\Gradle\gradle-4.4\bin**. Click OK to save.

Restart your computer than give it another try.

Hope this steps can help you.

Comment: I have follow the above step but it's not working any other solution for that ?